# I worked offshore in Norway, between 1978 and 1990. Will I be entitled to a Norwegian pension?

Tags: working, non-residents, norway, pension

I worked offshore in Norway, between the years 1978 and 1980. Would I be entitled to be legible for a Norwegian pension?

Comment: Were you working as an employee of a Norwegian company under Norwegian labor law?